# What event can I listen for in Laravel Spark for when a user signs up for a free TEAM trial?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-spark

To be clear, this is probably not the TeamSubscribed event because the team is not yet on a subscription. I am looking for when a trial is started- I need to run some code.

Comment: `Teams\TeamCreated`?

Answer (score 0):

have a look at [Team Events](https://spark.laravel.com/docs/5.0/teams#team-events):

```
Teams\TeamCreated //    A team has been created.
```